# How to make the document title appear in PDF bookmarks?

Tags: table-of-contents, titles, bookmarks

My sections and subsections appear in the bookmarks, but the title does not. I've seen papers including their titles as bookmarks in the PDF.

Answer (score 7):

You can add a bookmark manually using `\bookmark{<title>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bookmark}% http://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark
\title{My title}
\author{Me}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\bookmark[named=FirstPage]{\@title}
\makeatother
\maketitle
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsection{Another subsection}
\section{Another section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsection{Another subsection}
\end{document}
```

I've used

```
\makeatletter
\bookmark[named=FirstPage]{\@title}
\makeatother
```

in order to use the given `\title`. However, you could respecify the title and drop the `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` pair.